# Does the Ubuntu upload oops to kernelopps.org?

Tags: kernel, apport, whoopsie

I would like my kernel oops to be send to http://kerneloops.org. Ubuntu uses Whoopsie/Apport to intercept these crashes but sends them to https://daisy.ubuntu.com.

Does Whoopsie/Apport send these oops to http://kerneloops.org as well?

How can I configure it to do so?

Answer (score 1):

There is a kerneloops daemon and that one sends crash reports to kerneloops.org (see the [kerneloops-daemon package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kerneloops-daemon) ) so there should be no need for Whoopsie to send those to kerneloops (analysis could be an exception).

If that deamon is active crash reports will be sent to kerneloops.org

Comment: This is what I thought, but I cannot find any of my oops in kerneloops.org and the total number of reports submitted by Ubuntu users in the last week is "8". A bit too low I'd say.

Comment: Hmmm good point. Wondering: if that daemon is no longer active during an install... and whoopsie does not report them... could be this should be considered a bug. Mind you: I then also would assume whoopsie should push those to kerneloops.